# [__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - GADRequest error or AdMob getting crashed

Tags: objective-c, xcode9.3

[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xxxxxxxxx
 - GADRequest error or AdMob getting crashed.

Answer (score 0):

***Solution***:

Change **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in your **info.plist** from String to **Array**.